# Postfixadmin - alias and e-mail account

Tags: dovecot, postfix

I've installed `dovecot`, `postfix` and `postfixadmin`. Everything is OK, but I have some issues with sending email.

I would like to have something similar what I had on server with DirectAdmin.

For example I'm creating `contact@company.com` and additionally I'm creating an alias:

```
contact@company.com -> myprivateaccount@gmail.com
```

I know I can download e-mails directly from Gmail by IMAP/POP3 but forwarding is faster.

But this can't be done in `postfixadmin`, because when I set up `contact@company.com` I can't add the alias with the same username.

Why I want alias and email account at the same time?

1. Alias - for fast forwarding to my private account on Gmail.
2. E-mail account - for sending emails through this account by Gmail ("Sending mail from a different address" feature in Gmail)

Of course I could do something like this:

Aliases:

```
contact@company.com -> myprivateaccount@gmail.com
support@company.com -> myprivateaccount@gmail.com
customer@company.com -> myprivateaccount@gmail.com
```

E-mail account:

```
sender@company.com
```

I could log in with Gmail to this account to sending emails from {contact,support,customer}@company.com.

But I'm not sure if that solution is correct. If it is not how this should be done properly?

The ultimate goal is to have a copy of every email that arrives in `contact@company.com` to also be sent to `myprivateaccount@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, inside the postfixadmin configuration file, there is an option to allow the editing of actual email addresses as aliases, alias_control is the option.

I actually had this set up, when I created a new email there would be another link in the column to the right of the name (called Alias), and you could click it, and the Alias would (obviously) be the email address. You could add extra destinations at that time.